# JavaFX - Loading images and memory problems

Tags: java, image, memory, javafx, load

I've got a problem with loading images into my application. I'm trying to make a simple image browser. On the left I've got a list of folders. After clicking on folder's name on the list images should appear on the right(flow pane). Every image is in a HBox with a border.
But I'm getting error like this quickly:

```
java.lang.outofmemoryerror java heap space
```

I looked on task manager - if I load only 6 photos the app takes 500mb of memory!
And another thing - if I change folder on the list the memory remains taken.
While choosing another folder I'm creating new flowPane

```
flowPane = new FlowPane();
```

So the old one with all the ImageViews should be deleted by the garbage collector, right?

How can I manage images in my app effectively?

```
  for(int i = 0 ; i < zdjecia.length; i++){
        ImageView iv2 = new ImageView();
        Image image = new Image("file:"+zdjecia[i].getAbsolutePath());
         iv2.setImage(image);
         if( image.getHeight() > image.getWidth()){
                iv2.fitHeightProperty().bind(szerokoscZdjecia.multiply(0.8).subtract(6));
        }else
                iv2.fitWidthProperty().bind(szerokoscZdjecia.subtract(6));

         iv2.setPreserveRatio(true);
         iv2.setSmooth(true);
         iv2.setCache(false);

         String styl = "-fx-border-color: #b2b3b3;"
                 + "-fx-border-width: 2;";

         HBox boxNaFotke = new HBox();
         boxNaFotke.prefWidthProperty().bind(szerokoscZdjecia);
         boxNaFotke.prefHeightProperty().bind(szerokoscZdjecia.multiply(0.8));
         boxNaFotke.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
         boxNaFotke.setStyle(styl);
         boxNaFotke.getChildren().add(iv2);
         fotki.add(boxNaFotke);
         flowPane.getChildren().add(boxNaFotke);
    }
```

Comment: I have a same problem:(

Answer (score 4):

If you scale the `Image` using the [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#Image%28java.lang.String,%20double,%20double,%20boolean,%20boolean%29), the amount of the needed memory will be reduced dramatically.

**Some example from the documentation:**

> // load an image and resize it to 100x150 without preserving its original aspect ratio
>   // The image is located in my.res package of the classpath
>   `Image image2 = new Image("my/res/flower.png", 100, 150, false, false);`
>
> // load an image and resize it to width of 100 while preserving its
>  //
>   original aspect ratio, using faster filtering method 
> // The image is
>   downloaded from the supplied URL through http protocol 
>   `Image image3 = new Image("http://sample.com/res/flower.png", 100, 0, false, false);`

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem with memory in JavaFX but connected with setStyle method. I've analysed heap usage and I've found that StyleHelper object keeps all references to all styles set by setStyle method (a lot of HashMap instances with GC root in com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager$Holder). It might be an issue when style is often changed.

Try to comment boxNaFotke.setStyle(styl); line and check if it helps.